# cannot open my jar files on another computer

Tags: java, jar

I have created the jar file for one of my project and exported it to my computer. 
I have successfully done all this stuff including the generation and saving of the manifest file.

I am able to run the compiled file on my pc but not able to run it on another pc. I had compressed all the files and mailed it to a friend. It says : "cannot access the file" when I click on the jar executable to run my code.

I have a JRE installed on the other pc.

Comment: What file is it trying to access? Did you extract all the files out of the zip? Make sure they are all extracted and in the same directory.

Comment: Have you try to run the jar from command line, like `java -jar file.jar` so you can read better the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are putting some neccessery files or drivers on your PC during developing your project. So when you try to open your jar at your machine it looks and successfuly finds neccessery files. But when you send your application to your friend and he tries to start application then application looks and doesn't find these files or drivers on friend's PC...